# How do I set the position and size of an NSOpenPanel dialog?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I don't have much experience with programming for Mac, I come from a Windows background.

So, I use this code to show an NSOpenPanel, but I also want to specify the position and size on screen of the dialog when it appears. How do I do that?

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel  = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[openPanel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
NSInteger result    = [openPanel runModalForTypes:nil];
```

### Edit

---

It seems that by calling

```
[openPanel setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 500, 500) display:YES];
```

I can set the size of NSOpenPanel (it becomes 500x500 pixels), but not its upper-left corner, it's centered to the screen, instead of appearing at the top-left corner of the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to subclass NSOpenPanel and override the `center` method, which gets called before the panel is placed on screen. Here's how you would put it in the top right corner:

```
- (void)center {

    NSRect myFrame = [self frame];
    NSRect screenFrame = [[self screen] visibleFrame];

    myFrame.size.height = round(screenFrame.size.height / 2);
    myFrame.origin.x = screenFrame.origin.x + screenFrame.size.width - myFrame.size.width;
    myFrame.origin.y = screenFrame.origin.y + screenFrame.size.height - myFrame.size.height;

    [self setFrame:myFrame display:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'll need some time to read up on inheritance in Obejctive-C before I can follow your advice, the syntax seems a bit tricky, it's a lot different from C++.

Comment: The subclass doesn't play well with sandboxed apps unfortunately. ".... is not a supported subclass for sandboxing"

Answer (score 1):

NSOpenPanel inherits from NSWindow. I've never tried it, but it seems like you should be able to use the normal NSWindow methods to set its size and location.